# Angular Change Detection on Object with Map Property

Tags: angular, typescript

Ok, I've read numerous examples, but i'm just not quite putting this together. My goal is to create a component that shows a rough grid of the Context items. so that i can edit a few properties and send the changes back. However, the onChanges event doesn't capture changes to the map from elsewhere. I understand that has to do with the mutability of the object but what I'm really struggling to understand is what i'm supposed to do about that. Ive found doCheck, but it doesnt seem to detect changes either.

I have the following object:

```
export class PlanContext {

    selectedPlans: Map<number, ContextItem>;

    constructor() {
      this.selectedPlans = new Map<number, ContextItem>();
    }  

  addAllFromList(plans: Plan[]) {
    plans.forEach(v => {
    if (!this.isPlanSelected(v))
    this.addPlan(v);
   });
 }
// Functions Surrounding using the selectedPlans.
```

Here is the Container HTML

```
<div class="collapse w-100 show" [ngbCollapse]="!(planOpen$ | async)" aria-expanded="true">
   <div class="card w-100 text-left">
      <plancontextsummary-form [(planContext)]="plancontext"></plancontextsummary-form>
   </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding Component

```
export class ReadPlanContextSummaryPageComponent  {
  public planOpen$: Observable<boolean>;

  private _planContext: PlanContext;


  @Input()
  public set planContext(value: PlanContext) {
     this._planContext = value;
  }

  public get planContext(): PlanContext {
     return this._planContext;
  }

  constructor(public store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
     this.planOpen$ = store.select<boolean>(fromRoot.getPlanSummaryOpen);
  }
}
```

Here is the Form im struggling with.

```
export class PlanContextSummaryFormComponent implements DoCheck {

  @Input()
  planContext: PlanContext;

  differ: any;

  @Output()
  save  = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(protected fb: FormBuilder, private differs: IterableDiffers ) {
     this.differ = differs.find({}).create(null);
     this.createForm();
  }



  //ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  //  if (!this.planContext) {
  //    console.info("Still not detecting Input");
  //    //this.planContext = this.buildFakeContext();  // TODO: Remove Temp to make sure From functions correctly
  //  }

  //  for (let propName in changes) {
  //    console.info("Rebuilding " + this.planContext);
  //    if (propName === 'planContext') {
  //      if (this.planContext) {
  //        this.rebuildForm();
  //        this.isLoaded = true;
  //      }
  //    }
  //  }
  //}

  ngDoCheck() {
   ///TODO: STOP BEING STUCK
  }
}
//Form Logic
```

Its worth nothing that PlanContextSummaryFormComponent is a grandchild to the origin of PlanContext.

Grandparent as per request:

```
export class FindPlanPageComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
 businessUnits$: Observable<BusinessUnit[]>;
 plans$: Observable<Plan[]>;
 wellLifeCycleStageGates$: Observable<WellLifeCycleStageGate[]>;


 planContext: PlanContext;


 constructor(public store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { 
super();

     this.planContext = new PlanContext();

     this.wellLifeCycleStageGates$ = store.select<WellLifeCycleStageGate[]> 
     (fromRoot.getAllWellLifeCycleStageGates);
this.businessUnits$ = store.select<BusinessUnit[]> 
     (fromRoot.getAllBusinessUnits);
this.plans$ = store.select<Plan[]>(fromRoot.getAllPlans);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new BusinessUnitActions.Load());
  this.store.dispatch(new WellLifeCycleStageGateActions.Load());
  this.store.dispatch(new PlanActions.Search(null));
}

search(searchParameters: SearchParameters) {
  this.store.dispatch(new PlanActions.Search(searchParameters));
  this.clearPlanList();
}


 clearPlanList() {
    this.plans$.subscribe(plans => {
     this.planContext.clearList();
  });
}


addAllPlanList() {
  //this.planContext;
  this.plans$.subscribe(plans => {
    this.planContext.addAllFromList(plans);
  });
} 
  saveContext() {
console.info("Saving Context: " + this.planContext);

}

showPlanSummary() {
 this.store.dispatch(new LayoutActions.ShowPlanSummary());
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you set `PlanContext` in grandparent component?

Comment: @miselking - I added the grandparent. its also worth noting, that FindPlanPageComponent hasd another child that two way binds on PlanContext and is hunky dory.

Comment: So, the only way you are going to get any update in `ngOnChanges` for _Input_ is if you modify the `planContext` _instance_ (for example, you write `planContext = new PlanContext()`). If you only modify properties of _planContext_ then you will _not_ get updates for it in `ngOnChanges`.